# .htaccess rewrite for appending '?' to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

In attempting to use godaddy as a hosting provider I noticed when I use index.php/login I get a no input file specified error message. However, when I manually type index.php?/login the view I expect loads properly. Is there any way for me to do a rewrite so that I can append '?' to the end of index.php whenever it's in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```